# How to get list of weblogic applications via wlst

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I try to make inventory for some weblogic servers and expect to do it with WSLT.
I was able to get list of applications (100+) as from example http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=1473

```
connect('admin','xxxxxxx','t3://server1:7001')
cd('AppDeployments')
deplymentsList=cmo.getAppDeployments()

for app in deplymentsList:
      domainConfig()
      cd ('/AppDeployments/'+app.getName()+'/Targets')
      mytargets = ls(returnMap='true')
      domainRuntime()
      cd('AppRuntimeStateRuntime')
      cd('AppRuntimeStateRuntime')
      for targetinst in mytargets:
            curstate4=cmo.getCurrentState(app.getName(),targetinst)
            print '----', app.getApplicationName(), ' | ', app.getVersionIdentifier(), ' | ', app.getModuleType(), ' | ',  targetinst, ' | ', curstate4, ' | ', app.getSecurityDDModel(), ' | ', app.getAbsoluteSourcePath()
```

but i fail with some important info:

- Context Root
- Test Points

Can anybody help me to extract it?
And may be exists other way to enlist all applications on weblogic server with base properies?

// WebLogic Server Version: 12.2.1.0.0

Comment: for context root:  
`serverRuntime()  cd('/ApplicationRuntimes/VigieApp')  cc=cmo.getComponentRuntimes()  app=cc[0]

app.getContextRoot()`